# Flask Ajax data error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, python-3.x, flask

I am trying to send data from javascript/ajax (selected regions and city information) to flask and then return processed data back to javascript. The 'var data' look like  {"region1":"Asia","city1":"Taipei","region2":"S America"} on console.log.
I get error within ajax.

javascript:

```
 $(function() {
      $('#button').on('click', function() {
         var data = {'region1': $('select[name=slct1]').val(),
                    'city1': $('select[name=slct2]').val(),
                    'region2': $('select[name=slct3]').val()};
         console.log(data);
         $.ajax({
            url: '/receive',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            crossDomain: true,
            data: data,
            success: function(data2){
              alert('success');},
            error: function(){alert('failure');}
            });
        });
      });
```

Flask: Temp1 and other variables (np array) for City1 are extracted from pandas db.

```
@app.route('/receive', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def receive():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form['data']
        City1 = data['city1']
        Temp1 = some_function(City1) # np array

        return jsonify({'Temp1': list(Temp1)})
```

Comment: The data looks correct as per JSON standards. Please look at the browser's network tab using developer tools to see if the request is successfully sent to the server. Please observe your server-side logs to know what went wrong. If you need help with it, you should include the relevant excerpts of logs in your question as well.

Comment: Console the error and mention it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the data received in Flask should be parsed like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    data = request.get_data()
    data = json.loads(data)
    City1 = data['city1']
```

Comment: There were two errors in my code. One was I needed to modify the data before sending on js side (var data_JSON = JSON.stringify(data);. Second was what was suggested above. Thanks!